# Read file in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I must read text file in my Mobile Application on Windows Phone 7.1. I write my code :

```
IsolatedStorageFile fileStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
StreamReader Reader = null;
try
{
Reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("folder\\file.txt", FileMode.Open, fileStorage));
string textFile = Reader.ReadToEnd();

textBlock.Text = textFile;
Reader.Close();
}
catch
{
MessageBox.Show("File it not created");
}
```

All time when I try read this file, application show me MessageBox with text "file it not created". I don't have idea why application don't find my file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did something else create the file? If not, this is the expected behavior, as there is no file with the path. In the `IsolatedStorageFileStream` constructor, you passed [`FileMode.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx), which indicates "that the operating system should open an existing file. The ability to open the file is dependent on the value specified by the FileAccess enumeration. A System.IO.FileNotFoundException exception is thrown if the file does not exist." If you need to create the file, try `FileMode.CreateNew`, which indicates "that the operating system should create a new file. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission. If the file already exists, an IOException exception is thrown" or `FileMode.CreateOrOpen`.

Also, you might want to consider something like the following for your catch instead. It should get you more information, making debugging faster:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception opening file: " + ex.ToString());
}
```